# error C2664: 'bool Strless::operator ()(const TCHAR *&,const TCHAR *&) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'wchar_t *const ' to 'const TCHAR *&'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

I am struggling with a compilation error in the system , Here is the code

```
struct Strless : public binary_function<TCHAR*, TCHAR*, bool>
{   
public :

    bool operator()(const TCHAR* & _Left, const TCHAR* & _Right) const
    {   
        int iVal = _tcscmp(_Left, _Right);

        return (iVal < 0)? true:false;
    }


}; map<TCHAR *, int, Strless> mymap;
```

Comment: The message tells you what is wrong with your parameter type. Try to match it with what the compiler expects.

Comment: : Do you mind? Your Question title is hurting the eye.

Answer (score 2):

Your const is in the wrong place. The map is passing you a `TCHAR* const`, but you're taking a `const TCHAR*&`, which are not compatible. You want to take a `const TCHAR* const&`.

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to the problem (which has already been answered). But the following code is an abomination:

```
return (iVal < 0)? true:false;
```

The conditional operator is utterly redundant. The following works just as well:

```
return iVal < 0;
```

A code such as `condition ? true : false` should **always** be replaced by just `condition`. Never use boolean literals (`true`, `false`) except in assignment / initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're compiling your code in non-unicode fashion so that `TCHAR` is working out to `char` but you're explicitly using `wstring` or similar at the same time. You need to make sure that the types agree (using `value_type` from your string type can be helpful here).

Comment: Could be. Could also be the difference between `const x*` and `x* const`.